# What is the recommended practice for using scrollable tabs for date navigation?

Tags: tabs, datetimepicker

I am experimenting with using scrollable (aka swipe-able) tabs on Android as a navigation solution for browsing through weekly reports generated by an activity tracking app.

Users should be able to view report of the current week, as well browse through weekly reports of prior weeks. Attached are four screenshots of what I currently have - and not quite confident with. Note that my app will not generate "future reports", so the navigation should be from the current weekly report (i.e. This Week) and backwards to prior weeks.

[image: Weekly Reports as scrollable tabs]

[image: Weekly Reports as scrollable tabs]

[image: Weekly Reports as scrollable tabs]

[image: Weekly Reports as scrollable tabs]

Comment: Anybody.......?

Comment: How is your Activity Report data laid out, can't you just lay it out in top to bottom scroll-able manner....Starting from This week and going back as the user scrolls down....So if user is interested in viewing full report...he clicks on that week and goes to detailed report

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here are two solutions

***Solution 1)*** Use tapable controls instead of swipe. If the user wants to see 4th week report, he has to swipe 3 times (More Motor Load) So avoid too many swipes

[image: click tabs to go anywhere]

***Solution 2)*** Use a Drop-down instead at top, by default select This Week or Current week then let user decide which week he wants to see now

[image: drop-down selection]